# keytool Invalid keystore format

Tags: openssl, keytool

I am following this guide on Trusted Web Activity.
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/using-twa

I must now get the hash of my app's certificate, using :

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

debug.keystore is the temporary key created by Android Studio and Google Play will not allow apps signed with it, isn't it ?

So instead I put my key.pem and key.pk8 in a keystore folder and I replaced  *~/.android/debug.keystore*  with  *keystore/key.pk8* or *keystore/key.pem*.
But for both it says **Invalid keystore format** .

I created this two files with

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -key key.pem -out request.pem
openssl x509 -req -days 9999 -in request.pem -signkey key.pem -out certificate.pem
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -outform DER -in key.pem -inform PEM -out key.pk8 -nocrypt
```

An answer to a similar question tells to add *-storetype pkcs12* to the keytool command, but then I get this error :

> erreur keytool : java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag
>   type 45 java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 45
>           at sun.security.util.DerValue.toDerInputStream(DerValue.java:881)
>           at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:193
>   9)
>           at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
>           at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:823)
>           at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:366)
>           at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:359)

Answer (score 0):

For other people who may have the same problem, I eventually did this instead :

I made a keystore with Android Studio : key_store.jks

I used this file for the keytool command that I could not have working, and it worked.

Then I made .pk8 and .pem files from it following instructions on this page : https://roostertech.wordpress.com/2013/10/31/exporting-private-key-pk8-jks/